# Comparing two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to 2 columns eg. c & m,  with stock code items which I want to compare/find/match.
After I have found that specific stock code in column m, I need to compare the prices relating to stock codes in c & m, in colomns i and p and calculate the difference.
Can anybody please assist!

Comment: Welcome at superuser. Your question - as it is now - isn't clear enough. Please add some example data to show how your data is organized, and also some desired output.

Comment: Hi have an head office and a local store.

Comment: The head office stock code in column c needs to be compared with the stores stock code, somewhere in column m

Comment: After the stock code for the store has been found in column m, the price of the head office in column i, must be compared to the price of the stock code of the store in column p

Comment: The difference between the two prices will then have to be compared

Comment: None of the data is sorted

Comment: 2733423 ROYCO RECIPE BOLOGNAISE 200GR 12 156.00 0 18.89
2733427 ROYCO RECIPE BREYANI 200GR 12 156.00 0 18.89
2733431 ROYCO RECIPE BUTTER CHIC 200GR 12 156.00 0 18.89
2733435 ROYCO RECIPE CHIC CASS 200GR 12 156.00 0 18.89
2733439 ROYCO RECIPE BEEF CASS 200GR 12 156.00 0 18.89
2733443 ROYCO RECIPE CHIC A KING 200GR 12 156.00 0 18.89
2733465 ROYCO P/BAKE BACON&ONION 40GR 12 97.50 10.5 12.49

Comment: please don't answer in comments, but edit your question. Entering bulk data in comments doesn't improve quality.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the VLOOKUP function. You can find [more information and a quick tutorial here](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel-tips/how-to-use-excels-vlookup-function).

[image: Working example]

On the left side of my screen, I have my reference data. This is the set I want to search. On the right, I have my working data, this is what I want to compare with the reference data, and calculate the difference with.

Note that I have not formatted cells as currency.

The formula in column F is the key:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2, $A$2:$B$4, 2, FALSE)
```

This contains a few components. The first parameter is what I want to search for; the data in D2 (this formula was in F2). The second parameter is the set of data I want to compare to. Note the '$', this is very important; by including the '$' sign, you will stop the cell reference from changing when you copy this formula down the entire column. The '2' in the third position tells us that from our reference data, we want to get the value from the second column. The final parameter 'FALSE' lets the lookup know that the data is not sorted.

Note that VLOOKUP will search the first column of your data.

The second component is calculating the different, this is simple:

```
=ABS(E2-F2)
```

The subtraction works out the difference, the ABS function ensures that it is always positive. You may wish to keen the +/- however.

You should be able to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Imagine that column A in my example is your column C, column B is your column I, column D is your column M, and column E is your column P.

Comment: Imagine that my row 6 is your column B, but on a different sheet called "same sheet." Imagine that the sheet "different sheet" is your sheet, but in an alternate universe where the Mayans base 20 mathematical system dominates the planet. Now you should have a good basis for understanding what you need to do.